# Aligning trackbars in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I intend to create a opencv application which shows the output in the following way:

Output Window:
[image]

The application plays two videos side by side. Tracbkars 1 and 3 control video 1 (modify section Sub Image 1), and trackbars 2 and 4 control video 2 (modify section Sub Image 2).

I need to align the trackbars as shown in the image. How do i do that in opencv? cvCreateTrackbar does not provide any alignment operations.

What could be the alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, OpenCV controls are mostly useful for prototyping and quickly testing algorithm; for more advanced UI design you'd better use a separate tool.

Comment: I suppose I will have to move to something else for the UI. Will Qt be a good choice (w.r.t quickly and efficiently creating the application)?

Comment: Yup, Qt should do, though I have no experience in integrating it with OpenCV. There seem to be plenty of tutorials online, like http://develnoter.blogspot.fr/2012/05/integrating-opencv-in-qt-gui.html .

Comment: And Qt development is pretty efficient imo.

Comment: Thanks. Will accept your answer if nobody else comes with up any solution :)